# Is it posible to change layoutmanager for a different viewtype?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Actually I have two viewtypes, a recyclerview is showing the elements in a gridLayout fashion.

Problem is that one of those elements in the grid should be show horizontally with a linearlayout aspect and the others as a grid.

How can I manage this ?

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if(position %5 == 0) 1 else 0
    }
```

This is my recyclerview

```
binding.rv_mylist.adapter = TestAdapter()
binding.rv_mylist.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 3)
```

in conclusion, what I need is that viewtype 1 shows with a LinearLayoutManager and viewtype 0 with a GridLayoutManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by modify the `spanSizeLookup` of the `GridLayoutManager`, i.e.

```
layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 2).apply {
    spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
            return when(adapter.getItemViewType(position)) {
                 Type.Linear -> 1
                 Type.Grid -> 2
                 else -> 1
            }
        }
    })
}
recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

Comment: unable to resolve "Type", which dependency need to use here

Comment: Well, it is self-made class, you can replace with whatever you would prefer based on the getItemViewType() output

Comment: but is that possible to use Gridlayout manager into Linearlayout manager. Please suggest. I am using ExpendableRecyclerview

Comment: Well, can use GridLayoutManager instead and modify the `spanSizeLookup` as shown in the answer here